# Why using the libusb requires detaching the kernel driver?

Tags: linux, libusb

Why using the libusb requires detaching the kernel driver? Why isn't it possible to perform some USB IOs along with the kernel driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly to avoid confusion about the state of the USB-device. Each interface can only have one "user" at any given time.

Many USB-devices can enter different execution domains, cache-states, DMA transfers etc. These kinds of devices will then have state-machine-trackers in the driver, and it would easily fall out of sync or other types of conflicts. Not all devices are simple HID interfaces (which can be manipulated via other API's btw)

Comment: I first though of a real global linux limitation. Given the fact that this is precaution to avoid bypassing the kernel driver and introduce problems, I was able to use userland usb linux ioctls https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/usb/usbfs-ioctl.html together with the kernel driver, by making sure it doesn't interfere with it (it is a FTDI usb/serial converter device using the ftdi_sio kernel driver). The drawback of detaching the kernel driver is that it creates udev events, which causes troubles in my case (I listen them and I don't expect a device to disappear while I use it...).

Answer (score 0):

In order to communicate, each USB device have endpoints. These endpoint are like pipes, in these pipes all the data are travalling.

One endpoint have only one direction and can be use just by 1 driver.

So you need to detach the kernel driver in order to make available these endpoints.

If you want you can always detect and desactivate the driver which use the device in order to avoid the use of detach kernel driver.